# How to change the size of html div element with text inside it

Tags: javascript, html

I have an DIV element on my page with some text inside it which is less the size of the DIV element.

I also have a javascript function that uses setTimeout to animate the change of width property of the element.

However when the width becomes less than the width of the text inside it the text breaks on new line and so on. I tried using white-space:nowrap which makes the text stay on the same line but when the width of the element becomes less than the text width the text stays outside of it.

How to make the text stay on the same line AND hides along the div container?

Comment: SO Won't let me delete my own accepted answer but @Popoola deserves it.  His answer was right the first time (and correct before mine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add one more bit of CSS ([demo](http://cssdesk.com/haef2)):

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Answer (score 3):

Add ( overflow:hidden ) to the div element. ([demo](http://cssdesk.com/haef2))

Comment: SO is an amazing resource, and I want to do what I can to encourage more people to use it (having accepted answer taken away can be really frustrating, especially early on)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

white-space: pre-wrap